# Difference Between Adjacent Column Pairs in SAS and r

Tags: r, arrays, loops, sas

I would like to take the difference between columns 1 & 2, 3 & 4, 5 & 6, 7 & 8, and so on.
I originally had 55 corresponding column pairs (110 columns total) and needed to get 55 difference columns. I ended up coding each column difference by hand, but I thought I could probably do this much more efficiently. Perhaps by the use of arrays in SAS. I would like to solve this problem in r as well.

Synthetic data is below and if anyone knows how to quickly generate sequential paired column names like var1_apple, var1_banana, var2_apple, var2_banana, var3_apple, var3_banana,..., in r (without just typing out a vector of column names) that would be very helpful as well.

Thank you!

```
## create a dataframe with random values of 1:10. ncols x nrows = 200
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 200, replace = TRUE), ncol = 20, nrow = 10))
```

Comment: "column pairs"  What does that mean?  Sounds like the data is organized poorly for the analysis your want to do.  If instead of one observation with 110 variables you instead had 55 observations of three variable it would be trivial to calculate the difference between the two values for all 55 pairs.

Comment: Hi Tom, I actually have 70 observations. It is patient data comprised of 55 different protein levels from nasal and plasma samples. So the columns are in pairs like protein1_nasal, protein1_plasma, protein2_nasal, protein2_plasma, etc.

Comment: So you have 4 variables: PATIENT, PROTEIN, NASAL and PLASMA. and 70*55 observations.

Comment: Thank you, yes, then back to wide form for the macro I'm using in SAS to analyze and output the table. It works, but not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a SAS solution. As far as I understood your data looks like that: I tried to generate an example for 4 patients and 6 proteins, and two values for each protein (nasal and plasma).

```
data proteinvalues;
patient=1;
protein1_nas=12; protein1_plas=13; protein2_nas=6; protein2_plas=8;
protein3_nas=23; protein3_plas=24; protein4_nas=15; protein4_plas=15;
protein5_nas=45; protein5_plas=47; protein6_nas=56; protein6_plas=50;
output;
patient=2;
protein1_nas=1; protein1_plas=5; protein2_nas=6; protein2_plas=8;
protein3_nas=2; protein3_plas=4; protein4_nas=7; protein4_plas=9;
protein5_nas=3; protein5_plas=3; protein6_nas=8; protein6_plas=7;
output;
patient=3;
protein1_nas=0; protein1_plas=1; protein2_nas=20; protein2_plas=19;
protein3_nas=33; protein3_plas=5; protein4_nas=19; protein4_plas=20;
protein5_nas=32; protein5_plas=8; protein6_nas=12; protein6_plas=14;
output;
patient=4;
protein1_nas=4; protein1_plas=5; protein2_nas=9; protein2_plas=11;
protein3_nas=4; protein3_plas=6; protein4_nas=78; protein4_plas=70;
protein5_nas=4; protein5_plas=7; protein6_nas=78; protein6_plas=77;
output;
run;
```

OK, this data generating step is not quite elegant, but it works...

Here is my solution by using an array with all protein-variables as members. The value pairs are then adjacent members in the array, i.e. No.1/No.2 , No.3/No.4  etc...

```
/* Number of proteins, in your data 55, in my data 6 */
%let NUM_PROTEINS=6;

data result (keep=patient diff:);
set proteinvalues;
/* Array definition with all variable names starting with "protein" */
array protarr{*} protein:;
/* Array for the resulting values */
array diff(&NUM_PROTEINS.);
/* Initializing the protein number */
num_prot=0;
/* Loop over the protein by step 2 = one iteration per protein */
do n=1 to dim(protarr) by 2;
   /* p is plasma, n is nasal value */
   p=n+1;
   /* setting the protein number */
   num_prot+1;
   /* calculate the difference, using sum-function to handle missing values */
   diff{num_prot}=sum(protarr{p},-protarr{n});
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT -- added the "55 difference columns" part at the bottom.

---

Adjusting data to be column pairs:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 200, replace = TRUE), ncol = 20, nrow = 10))
names(df) <- paste0("var", rep(1:10, each = 2), "_", rep(c("apple", "banana")))


names(df)
[1] "var1_apple"   "var1_banana"  "var2_apple"   "var2_banana"  "var3_apple"   "var3_banana" 
 [7] "var4_apple"   "var4_banana"  "var5_apple"   "var5_banana"  "var6_apple"   "var6_banana" 
[13] "var7_apple"   "var7_banana"  "var8_apple"   "var8_banana"  "var9_apple"   "var9_banana" 
[19] "var10_apple"  "var10_banana"
```

---

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = c("var", ".value"), names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 100 × 4
     row var   apple banana
   <int> <chr> <int>  <int>
 1     1 var1      8      7
 2     1 var2      4      9
 3     1 var3      7      3
 4     1 var4      6     10
 5     1 var5     10     10
 6     1 var6      1      1
 7     1 var7      2     10
 8     1 var8      7      9
 9     1 var9      3      8
10     1 var10     2      6
# … with 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

Here a variation to add all the difference columns interspersed:

```
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = c("var", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  mutate(difference = banana - apple) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = apple:difference, 
              names_glue = "{var}_{.value}", names_vary = "slowest")
```

Result (truncated)

```
# A tibble: 10 × 10
     row var1_apple var1_banana var1_difference var2_apple var2_banana var2_difference var3_apple var3_banana var3_difference
   <int>      <int>       <int>           <int>      <int>       <int>           <int>      <int>       <int>           <int>
 1     1          7          10               3          5           3              -2          1           9               8
 2     2          9           2              -7          3           6               3          8           1              -7
 3     3          2          10               8          3           3               0          7           8               1
 4     4          3           1              -2          8           3              -5          9           9               0
 5     5          2           7               5          7          10               3          6           9               3
 6     6          5           4              -1          2           1              -1          5           4              -1
 7     7          4           5               1         10           3              -7          9           4              -5
 8     8         10           7              -3          3           2              -1          5           9               4
 9     9          5           5               0          7           3              -4         10           7              -3
10    10         10           6              -4          1           4               3         10          10               0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @Tom's comment is spot-on. Restructuring the data probably makes sense if you are working with paired data. E.g.:

```
od <- names(df)[c(TRUE,FALSE)]
ev <- names(df)[c(FALSE,TRUE)]

data.frame(
    odd      = unlist(df[od]),
    oddname  = rep(od,each=nrow(df)),
    even     = unlist(df[ev]),
    evenname = rep(ev,each=nrow(df))
)
##      odd oddname even evenname
##X11     7      X1   10       X2
##X12     6      X1    1       X2
##X13     2      X1    6       X2
##X14     5      X1    2       X2
##X15     3      X1    1       X2
## ...
```

It is then trival to take one column from another in this structure.

If you must have the matrix-like output, then that is also achievable:

```
od <- names(df)[c(TRUE,FALSE)]
ev <- names(df)[c(FALSE,TRUE)]
setNames(df[od] - df[ev], paste(od, ev, sep="_"))

##   X1_X2 X3_X4 X5_X6 X7_X8 X9_X10 X11_X12 X13_X14 X15_X16 X17_X18 X19_X20
##1     -3     2     4     4     -2       4       3       1      -3       9
##2      5     5     4     3     -1       3      -1      -3       5      -2
##3     -4     3     7     4     -5       1       1       5      -4       4
##4      3     0     6     3      4      -5       6       6      -7       4
##5      2     2     1     4     -6      -3       6       2       3       1
##6     -6    -2     4    -2      0       1       3       0       0      -7
##7      0    -6     3     7     -1       0       0      -5       3       1
##8     -1     3     3     1      2      -2      -5       3       0       0
##9     -4     1    -5    -2     -4       7       6      -2       4      -4
##10     2    -7     4    -1      0      -6      -4      -4       0       0
```